# Meteor remote collection - hooks don’t work

Tags: javascript, meteor, hook

I have to connect to the external database and get access to its collections. It works fine, when I use it, but the problem is when I need collection hooks, e.g. Collection.after.insert(function(userId, doc)). The hook is not being fired. I have following code:

```
// TestCollection.js

let database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor",
{
    oplogUrl: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/local'
});
let TestCollection = new Mongo.Collection("testCollection", { _driver: database });
module.exports.TestCollection = TestCollection;
console.log(TestCollection.findOne({name: 'testItem'})); // writes out the item correctly

// FileUsingCollection.js
import { TestCollection } from '../collections/TestCollection.js';
console.log(TestCollection.findOne({name: 'testItem'})); // writes out the item correctly second time

TestCollection.after.update(function (userId, doc) {
  console.log('after update');
}); // this is NOT being fired when I change the content of remote collection (in external app, which database I am connected)
```

How to make this work?

EDIT:

I have read many hours about it and I think it might be connected with things like:
- oplog
- replicaSet

But I am newbie to Meteor and can’t find out what are those things about. I have set MONGO_OPLOG_URL and I added oplog parameter to database driver as I read here: https://medium.com/@lionkeng/2-ways-to-share-data-between-2-different-meteor-apps-7b27f18b5de9
but nothing changed. And I don’t know how to use this replicaSet, how to add it to the url. Anybody can help?

Comment: Where's the code where you're adding the hook(s)?

Comment: Its the whole instruction: `TestCollection.after.update(function (userId, doc)...` it should add the hook.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the comment on the last line at first.  `// this is NOT being fired when I change the content of remote collection (in external app, which database I am connected)` [matb33:collection-hooks](https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks) hooks updates from your meteor app. It does not observe changes to the collections made by another app tied to the same db. That's where observers can be helpful as they are watching the db. OTOH an observer cannot implement a *before* hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try something like below code,

```
    var observer = YourCollections.find({}).observeChanges({
            added: function (id, fields) {

             }
        });
```

You can also have `'addedBefore(id, fields, before)'`, `'changed(id, fields)'`, `'movedBefore(id, before)'`, `'removed(id)'`

For more features [goto link](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges).

Comment: It doesn't work, the function connected with the e.g changed hook does not fire.

Comment: Observer worked! I updated Meteor to 1.5.1 and cleaned up the code and now it's fine. Thanks!